# Return dynamically populated object literal in javascript

Tags: javascript

A little new to JS. It seems to me something like this would be possible, but after spending a few hours of getting nowhere, I'm wondering if there actually is a way to make something like this work. It's just a function that returns an object, but the key values are set in the function instead of being passed to it:

```
function makeProduct() {
      return {
          Id: '0',
          Name: document.getElementById('Name').value,
          Price: document.getElementById('Price').value,
          Category: document.getElementById('Category').value
      };
    }
```

It seems like this would save a lot of duplicate code, instead of having to get the user input, assign it to variables, and then populate the object with the more proper syntax:

```
function product(id, name, price, category) ...
```

I was able to accomplish what I was trying to do with a class, but it does generate a lot more code. If you had a large object, you are typing a lot of the same things multiple times.

I do have some code that works using jquery, but if I try and put it in a function that returns the object, it errors out on me, too.

The whole point of the code is to call the function, return the object, and use Axios to send it to my webAPI.

```
async function makeGetRequest() {

  var product = makeProduct();

let res = await axios.post('http://localhost:56730/api/product/', product);

let data = res.data;
console.log(data);
}
```

And it does work as expected with my class.

Also, because of the keywords in this question, this is something really hard to search for and get relevant answers.

Comment: `=` should be `:` in an object literal.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend to achieve. What do you mean by "key values are set in the function instead of being passed to it" mean?

Comment: "*spending a few hours of getting nowhere*" - the `makeProduct` function you posted is totally fine and should work. What is the problem? What happens that you don't expect? Can you make a [mcve] (including the html form markup for the inputs you're trying to read)?

Comment: Vlaz, I tried it both ways and it errored out or didn't set the values every single time. I swapped them back to : and it just worked. I spent almost three hours trying different things before posting that question.

Comment: Spankied, if you google making an object, every example is passing a the value to a function like "function User(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth)" I was just trying to compact this to "function User()" and set the value inside the function directly from user input using getElementById. I couldn't find any examples of that anywhere.

Comment: Bergi, when it didn't just error out, it was returning null values for my input from the textboxes. Sometimes my makeGetRequest would be undefined just from putting the makeProduct() function in the code.  As Vlaz pointed out, I had = there, but I did try it both ways before posting my question. The = came in when I was trying to use the this.Category = ... syntax and returning that. That didn't work either. Thus my post here.